# Efficient Redirect code for the htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, pagerank

Looking for an efficient Redirect code for the htaccess. 
There are about 200 links (practically all requests will go through the redirect)

Goals:

1. `http://example.com/pages.shtml` to be redirected to `http://example.com/pages`
2. should be 301 redirect keeping in mind page rank preservation

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.shtml http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you Timofey Stolbov!!

A sub question...... what is more efficient/effective in this situation.  



    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.shtml http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

OR 

    RewriteRule (([^/]+/)*[^/]+)\.(s?html?)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]